# Sparse matrix manipulation

Tags: python, numpy

I have an original matrix that looks something like this:

```
(32, 69901)     1
(108, 69901)    1
(32, 69902)     1
(108, 69903)    1
(108, 69904)    1
(432, 69905)    1
(432, 69906)    1
(432, 69907)    1
```

I want to separate the first X rows into one matrix and the rest into another matrix. I tried doing it with a simple for loop that looks like this:

```
mat1 = []
mat2 = []
for i,line in enumerate(original_matrix):
        if i < cutoff:
            mat1.append(line)
        else:
            mat2.append(line)
```

But that makes a matrix that looks like this:

```
with 223 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, <1x103515 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
with 253 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, <1x103515 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
with 142 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, <1x103515 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
with 222 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, <1x103515 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
```

How do I make it look like the original?

Comment: Can you post how you generate the sparse matrix? Some small minimum example might be sufficient.

Comment: That's basically my return value from a CountVectorizer function found in scikit-learn.

Comment: According to the `scikit-learn` documentation, this function returns `'This implementation produces a sparse representation of the counts using scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to change what type of sparse matrix you use.  It looks like you are using a compressed sparse column matrix (csc).  Consider using a compressed sparse row matrix (csr) if you need to break it up by rows (I think doc and lil sparse matrices will also work, but I didn't fully test them).  For instance, let's start with a csc matrix.

```
In [1]: from scipy import sparse

In [2]: original_matrix = sparse.csc_matrix(([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
([32, 108, 32, 108, 108, 432, 432, 432], [69901, 69901, 69902, 
69903, 69904, 69905, 69906, 69907])), shape=[500,103515])

In [3]: print original_matrix
  (32, 69901)   1
  (108, 69901)  1
  (32, 69902)   1
  (108, 69903)  1
  (108, 69904)  1
  (432, 69905)  1
  (432, 69906)  1
  (432, 69907)  1
```

We can't split this up by rows using array splicing, but we can convert our csc matrix to a car matrix quite easily.

```
In [4]: new_matrix = original_matrix.tocsr()
Out[4]:
<500x103515 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [5]: print new_matrix
  (32, 69901)   1
  (32, 69902)   1
  (108, 69901)  1
  (108, 69903)  1
  (108, 69904)  1
  (432, 69905)  1
  (432, 69906)  1
  (432, 69907)  1
```

This can be split up by using array splicing if you have a car, doc or lil type sparse matrix.

```
In [6]: cutoff = 100

In [7]: mat1 = original_matrix[:cutoff]

In [8]: mat2 = original_matrix[cutoff:]
```

Would give you the two pieces that you were looking for.  Note that the cutoff is the row of the actual matrix, not what you see when you call the print statement.

```
In [9]: print mat1
  (32, 69901)   1
  (32, 69902)   1

In [10]: print mat2
  (108, 69901)  1
  (108, 69903)  1
  (108, 69904)  1
  (432, 69905)  1
  (432, 69906)  1
  (432, 69907)  1
```

If you don't have a csc matrix as I've assumed, the there are built-in methods to convert other types of sparse matrices to csr as well.